# Issue in path,regex match in app.yaml

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app.yaml

I have a request path:/report-from-down coming in and my expectation is should be handled by last handler : (.*)
I have these definitions in my app.yaml.

```
- url: /login|/report|/stats/.*|/report/data
  script: main.app

- url: /api/.*|/auth|/dashboard
  script: main.app

- url: .*
  script: other.app
```

I wonder why its being handled by the first handler in above list.
I was not working good earlier when we tested in past, I think something changed at appengine side causing this.

I changed the app.yaml to this below and now I see  path:/report-from-down is being handled by (.*) again.

```
- url: /report
  script: main.app

- url: /login|/report|/stats/.*|/report/data
  script: main.app

- url: /api/.*|/auth|/dashboard
  script: main.app

- url: .*
  script: other.app
```

Can any one explain if this is expected or what is causing this.

Comment: Try putting parenth's around each one, as well as the dollar sign. I.e. `(/login|/report|/stats/.*|/report/data)$` Or even this `/(login|report|stats/.*|report/data)$`

Comment: Ya got that but was surprised this is caused because of change in appengine infrastructure.

Comment: There's been no change that I know of, and I'd be very surprised if that ever worked.

Comment: Why do we need the `$` sign? It seems to work the same without it now... Actually, do we *still* need to add the `$` sign? Or did Google change it to match the entire text by default, rather than just the prefix?